# Submission of xhtml file as a stream to Chiba

Tags: xforms, xforms-betterform

As I am new to Chiba, I want to know how to integrate Chiba to my JSP & Servlet Application and how to submit a xhtml file to Chiba as a stream and get output as a HTML+CSS+JS/AJAX.

What I want to achieve:

1. Submit a xform to Chiba using a stream or as a file through JSP and Servlet.
2. To get the output form from Chiba as a HTML, CSS, JS and AJAX.
3. The created xhtml x-form that will be used by Customers to fill in data.
4. On submit, the instance xml goes to a servlet.
5. The Servlet then saves this instance xml.

Where can I find a example for implementing Chiba with a Java application. I tried to implement it with my application but didn't get success as there is very less information in Cookbook and User Guide of Chiba.

Thank you folks for any help. :)